# Git repository has two starting commits - how can I merge them?

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I'm converting a repository from TFS to Git and for some reason the start of my history looks like this:

```
*   - Merge from Staging
|\
| * - Foo
| * - Branched from $/TFS/Main
* - Branched from $/TFS/Staging
```

I.e. I have two unrelated initial commits that are merged into each other. The two initial commits are more-or-less equivalent, so what I'd like to do is "squash" the `Merge from Staging` and `Branched from $/TFS/Staging` commits, effectively removing the `Branched from $/TFS/Staging` commit so that my history looks like this:

```
* - Merge from Staging
* - Foo
* - Branched from $/TFS/Main
```

From what I can tell the normal way of doing this would be an interactive rebase starting with a commit before the branches diverged, but I don't have a commit like that in this repository.

How can I fix this mess?

Answer (score 2):

I have never used TFS (much less a TFS-to-Git conversion program) and cannot say why you got what you did, but the problem here is that you do in fact have two separate root commits, which can only become related through a merge commit.  Git needs every commit to be *reachable* via the parent links (outgoing arcs) from each commit node (vertex in the commit DAG).  Moreover, Git works by starting at the end—the most recent commits, found by their labels—and working backwards.

Let me re-draw the graph so that I can label each commit with a letter (and add more spacing, for visual emphasis).

```
D   - Merge from Staging
|\
| C - Foo
| |
| B - Branched from $/TFS/Main
|
A - Branched from $/TFS/Staging
```

Commit `D` is the *tip* commit, and presumably has the branch label `master` on it, so that Git can find it.

Commits `A` and `B` are both roots.  Commit `C` is a non-root commit whose parent is commit `B`.  Commit `D` ties the two branches together: one branch is rooted at `B`, the other is rooted at (and consists solely of) `A`.

Your goal is to drop `A` entirely.  To do this, you must also discard `D`.  That might be too drastic.

#### Copy and discard `D`

When you discard `D`, you give up any *difference between* the tree-snapshot stored under commit `D` and the tree-snapshot stored under commit `C`.  This may, or may not, be what you want as well.  There may be no difference between `D` and `C`, or no significant difference.  (To find out, have Git compare commits `C` and `D` directly: `git diff <hash-ID-of-C> <hash-ID-of-D>`, for instance.)

If you wish to keep the *tree* for `D`, while discarding commit `D` itself, you need to *copy* that tree to a new commit.  There are many ways to do this but the simplest is probably to cherry-pick the merge: check out commit `C` directly (by hash ID), create a branch there, `git cherry-pick -m <mainline-number> <hash-or-name-for-D>`.  The "mainline number" you use (1 or 2) determines which set of changes Git brings in: those when comparing `D` to `C`, or those when comparing `D` to `A`.  You want the ones obtained when comparing `D` to `C`, so that the final commit has the same *tree* as `D`.

(Since some converter presumably made `D`, I don't know how it arranged the parent links when it made this merge commit.  So I don't know whether you want `-m 1` or `-m 2` here.  An alternative way to deal with this is to use Git's *plumbing commands*, in this case, `git commit-tree`, but that's trickier to describe: the plumbing commands are meant for use in scripts, not for use by humans.)

Hence, assuming the branch name `master` identifies commit `D`:

```
$ git checkout <hash-id-of-C>
$ git checkout -b new-master
$ git cherry-pick -m <number> master
```

The result is a graph that looks like this:

```
D   - Merge from Staging  (master)
|
| E - copy of D           (new-master)
|\|
| C - Foo
| |
| B - Branched from $/TFS/Main
|
A - Branched from $/TFS/Staging
```

You can now proceed to the "discard D" step below.

#### Discard `D`

If the *tree* for commit `D` is useless, you can just drop `D` entirely, not bothering to copy the tree to a new commit at all.  This is easier since you don't have to do the cherry-pick (or `git commit-tree`).

Or, if you have already successfully copied `D` to `E`, you can now discard `D` since `E` has the copy you want.

To do *that*—to discard `D` now—you just need to force the branch name (I'll assume `master` here again) to point directly to commit `C`:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard <hash-id-of-C>
```

This means that Git will start by looking first at commit `C`, which is the second one you wanted kept, then continue on to look at `C` parent, which is `B`.  Git would then try to continue on to `B`'s parent, but since it's a root commit and *has* no parent, Git stops there, and you have only commits `C` and `B`.  The original `D` and `A` are still there, in your repository, preserved through Git's *reflogs* for a period.  Eventually the reflogs expire as well, commits `A` and `D` become unprotected, and Git's *garbage collector*, `git gc`, removes them forever.

#### Re-incorporating the copy

If you made a commit `E` on branch `new-master`, now is the time to pick it up.  You now have this:

```
D   - Merge from Staging  [abandoned - no name]
|
| E - copy of D           (new-master)
|\|
| C - Foo                 (master)
| |
| B - Branched from $/TFS/Main
|
A - Branched from $/TFS/Staging
```

which we can re-draw without `D` and `A` at all as:

```
E - copy of D           (new-master)
|
C - Foo                 (master)
|
B - Branched from $/TFS/Main
```

All we have to do is get Git to move the name `master` "forward" so that it points to commit `E`:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --ff-only new-master
```

for instance.  This gives us:

```
E - copy of D           (master, new-master)
|
C - Foo
|
B - Branched from $/TFS/Main
```

Note how no *commit* changes, *ever*.  We just add *new* commits.  What does change, besides the new commits, is that *branch names* (like `master`) move around so that they point to newer commits—or, for special cases like our `git reset`, they may even move "backwards".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fix the history, there are several ways :

from the `Merge from Staging` commit, you can run :

```
# if $hash is the hash of the '- Foo' commmit :
git rebase -i $hash

# you will see a list with one commit :
# set the command to "edit" (instead of "pick")
# close the editor

# when git says "You can amend the commit ...", run :
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: Hmm, so when I did that I got a merge conflict, which I don't understand

Comment: I've tried a bunch of options in the interactive rebase, but having no success so far - squash tells me `error: cannot 'squash' without a previous commit`, and none of the other options get rid of that extra dangling commit

Comment: That would typically be a way to deal with this kind of thing, but it does not work at all for this case. Normally, rebase drops merges entirely, but you have to have a starting commit on which to rebase. Here there are two potential starting points and both are root commits; rebase is not prepared to handle this.